# How to connect socket io in useEffect in React 18?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-18

I just updated to React 18 and I noticed that the useEffect runs twice which makes my socket io code fail connection. What could be the solution for this?

Here is my useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(connect());
    return () => dispatch(disconnect());
  }, []);
```

This is supposed to run on mount so just once but with the new changes in React 18, it does not. I get the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4444/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=tvz2_YPur_k2czFbAAAo' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

When I remove the StrictMode, it works fine as usual so the problem comes from the new useEffect change in react 18.

EDIT:
So I played with it more and I noticed that if I remove the `return () => dispatch(disconnect())` from the cleanup, it works fine.

Why would that be?

Like this:

```
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(connect());
      }, []);
```

Comment: add **dispatch** to the `useEffect dependencies`

Comment: @monim Adding dispatch to the dependencies does not help. Check my editted question now.

Comment: StrictMode will cause everything to be rendered twice in development mode.

Comment: @matthiasgiger Yes, I saw that on the official docs, it is on purpose apparently so I wonder how to make my code work again with this new change. In my case its supposed to run only on mount and even if it renders 2 times, the cleanup has to make sure this is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately WebSockets are a stateful communication layer, and React tries to be a stateless library. React 18 strict mode always mounts and unmounts multiple times reveal statefulness.

You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-websocket, a library that has a global socket manager outside of React that gives you access to sockets.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I actually noticed that if I remove the cleanup part of the useEffect where I do disconnect, it works fine.

Comment: Good to know. You could also consider checking to see if the [socket is connected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/readyState) with `websocket.readyState` before trying to close it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can add an empty dependency array to ensure that the effect only runs once when the component mounts:

> Notice: Remove <React.StrictMode> from the first component and let's
> see fix twice run or not.

try this code to connect websocket:

```
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from 'websocket';

const websocketURL = 'Your WebSocket Connection';

const SampleWebSocket= () => {
       useEffect(() => {
         const websocket = new W3CWebSocket(websocketURL);
           
         websocket.onerror = (err) => console.warn('ERROR websocket', err);

         websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));

        *//it possible to set up an interval to send a ping to the server and keep the connection alive* 
            const pingInterval = setInterval(() => {
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify({ title: 'Pong' }));
            }, 30000);
        }


        return () => {

            clearInterval(pingInterval);
            websocket.close();

        };

       },[]);
}

export default SampleWebSocket;
```

Make sure websocket package has been installed `npm i websocket --develop`